# How to stop a program from running after Setup (Deployment Project) installer runs?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, oneclick

After I install a program in VS 2013 with a Deployment Project, the app runs. I need to give the user the option.

Even if I added a dialog, how could I stop the app from running after the installer exists?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about an installer on the desktop, which it sounds like, there should be a button. Usually once everything is installed there is a checkbox that says "Run" or something. Uncheck that.